# I already declared integer and tried to return integer but it gives me error

Tags: c++

```
int a;int b;int c;
```

If i want to return a, b, and c. how I should do that?
I did the following way. but it gives me error.

```
return a, b, c;
```

Comment: You'll want to read about the [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work).

Answer (score 3):

> If i want to return a, b, and c. how I should do that?

**Option 1**

Define a `struct` and return an object of the `struct`.

```
struct MyStruct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};
```

Now you can use:

```
return MyStruct{10, 20, 30};
```

**Option 2**

Use `std::tuple`.

```
using MyData = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
```

and then

```
return MyData{10, 20, 30};
```

Comment: Rather than define your own class you could just use `std::tuple`

Comment: @LokiAstari, that's also an option.

Answer (score 0):

While C++ doesn't allow you to return multiple values, you can return std::tuples, which are basically the same:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Or, if you want to be a bit more explicit, you can return a struct.

Alternatively, you can take an "output argument" by reference and overwrite it:

```
void returnTwoThings(int& out1, int&out2) {
    out1 = 42;
    out2 = 16;
}

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
returnTwoThings(a, b);

// Prints "a: 42 b: 16"
std::cerr << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << std::endl;
```

Comment: how to write this in c++ printf("The value is: (x1, y1) = (%d, %d), (x2, y2) = (%d, %d), (x3, y3) = (%d, %d)\n",
           x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);  ?

Comment: What's that got to do with your original question, what language is that to start with, and what are you even trying to _do_ anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can either return a `struct` containing all three integers

```
struct IntTrio
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

IntTrio foo()
{
    int a, b, c;
    // ...
    return {a, b, c};
}
```

You can also return an `std::tuple<int, int, int>`, though the brace syntax for return won't work in C++14, you will need `std::make_tuple`

Or you can simply return your favorite fixed-sized container, such as `std::array<int, 3>` containing all three values.

Comment: how to write this in c++ printf("The value is: (x1, y1) = (%d, %d), (x2, y2) = (%d, %d), (x3, y3) = (%d, %d)\n", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

Comment: @tani That seems like a completely different question. Ask a new question officially on the site

Answer (score 0):

**In C++ or C, you can return only one value/variable.** If you are returning an integer it should be only one `'int'`. If you want to return multiple values, put those values in a `'struct'`(structure) and change the return type of the function and proceed with returning the 'struct'.

```
struct StructureName
{  
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

struct StructureName functionName(input_arguments)
{   
struct StructureName var;
////your operations
var.a=10;
var.b=20;
var.c=30;
return var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically in C++ you can only return a single value from a function. To return more values you need to wrap them in a structure. Luckily the standard provides a type for this:

You can use `std::tuple` to return multiple values.

```
 std::tuple<int,int,int> getStuff()
 {
      return {2, 3, 4};
 }

 int main()
 {
     int x,y,z;

     // Don't need to use a tuple object to catch the result.
     // You can use std::tie to extract the values directly.
     std::tie(x, y, z) = getStuff();



     // If you don't want to use one of the values use `std::ignore`
     std::tie(x, std::ignore, z) = getStuff();


     // Or you can store them in a tuple.
     auto tup = getStuff();

 }
```